# ColdFusion Pop-Up Window appears and immediately closes

Tags: coldfusion

I have a really weird problem. I am trying to create a simple pop-up window in my ColdFusion application using `Coldfusion.Window.Create`. However, as soon as you click on the link and the pop-up windows appears on the screen, it immediately closes out by itself.

I have even tried making my target page blank with just **Hello World** text on it and it still closes out. What am I missing here?

Here's my code:

```
<cfajaximport tags="cfwindow">
<!---Capture New Signature --->
<a href="" onClick="ColdFusion.Window.create('Window1', 'Signature Capture',
        'https://#subscriber.hostName#.#subscriber.baseURL#/eztrax/administrator/tickets/templates/signature_popup.cfm?ticket_id=#get_ticket.ticket_id#',
        {x:100,y:100,height:300,width:400,modal:false,closable:true,
        draggable:true,resizable:true,center:true,initshow:true,
        minheight:200,minwidth:200 })">
     WindowsDotCreate - Capture New Signature  |  
</a>
```

Comment: Don't use cfwindow. Use [jQuery UI Dialog](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) or [Bootstrap Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) or _any_ JS library other than CF's built-in stuff.

Comment: I've upvoted @PeterBoughton's comment, but I will reiterate it too. Don't attempt to do UI stuff like this with CFML. Use proper clientside technology. CF is good for serverside stuff; it's rubbish @ UI stuff. You are backing yourself into a corner even starting out using CF for this requirement. See http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2014/1/23/Im-not-going-to-tell-you-to-stop-using-ColdFusion-UI-tags-anymore

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try to implement this using jQuery and see if it cooperates a little better. Thanks.

Comment: Cool. Close or delete the question then, eh?